# Can't precompile assets from Froala Editor on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, wysiwyg, froala

I tried to deploy on Heroku a version of my RoR app with [wysiwyg-rails](https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-rails) gem.

When deploying, I have this error message.

```
remote: -----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2021-04-22T10:52:42.317602 #460]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_aaf37ebc/public/assets/froala_editor.min-894cc2f9456887cbaa6c7354858aa99f6188c9b54b8a9905868a24672e3f0b5f.js
remote:        I, [2021-04-22T10:52:42.318156 #460]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_aaf37ebc/public/assets/froala_editor.min-894cc2f9456887cbaa6c7354858aa99f6188c9b54b8a9905868a24672e3f0b5f.js.gz
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...ax(36px, 36px))": expected ";", was "[auto-fill];gri..."
remote:        (sass):8
remote:        /tmp/build_aaf37ebc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1207:in `expected'
```

I also run `rake assets precompile` on my local machine and it works fine.

Do you have any ideas about how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found how to solve it.

Just updated sass-rails gem from v5 to v6.